# Fade page transition to an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, fade

I'm trying to make a smooth transition to a anchor within a page. The objective is when you click the link pointing to the anchor, the page fades out (scrolls) and fades in with the called anchor itself.

I have this mark-up, it fades in/out correctly, the URL changes to the called anchor, but it doesn't scroll to the called element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.transition").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $(".container").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);

  });

  function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
    $(".container").fadeIn(500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="A">This is A <a href="#B" class="transition">Go to B</a>
  </div>

  ...some large text...

  <div id="B" style="margin-top: 3000px;">This is B <a href="#A" class="transition">Go to A</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative using CSS and plain vanilla javascript:

```js
var initialiseFadePageLink = [];

function fadePage(i) {
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
var transitionAnchors = document.getElementsByClassName('transition');
var current = '#' + transitionAnchors[i].parentNode.getAttribute('id');
var destination = transitionAnchors[i].getAttribute('href');

transitionAnchors[i].setAttribute('href', current);
container.classList.add('fadeout');

setTimeout(function(){
window.location.hash = destination;
container.classList.remove('fadeout');
transitionAnchors[i].setAttribute('href', destination);
}, 1000);

}


function fadePageLinks(i) {
return function(){
var transitionAnchors = document.getElementsByClassName('transition');
transitionAnchors[i].addEventListener('click',function(){fadePage(i);},false);
};
}


function initialiseFadePageLinks() {
var transitionAnchors = document.getElementsByClassName('transition');
for (var i = 0; i < transitionAnchors.length; i++) {
initialiseFadePageLink[i] = fadePageLinks(i);
initialiseFadePageLink[i]();
}
}

window.addEventListener('load',initialiseFadePageLinks,false);
```

```css
#B {
margin-top: 3000px;
}

.container {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.container.fadeout {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="A">This is A <a href="#B" class="transition">Go to B</a></div>
...some large text...
<div id="B">This is B <a href="#A" class="transition">Go to A</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's amazing! This brings so many possibilites! Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you aren't passing the `linkLocation` variable to the `redirectPage` function. Clearly if `linkLocation` is a global variable, you can access it inside of the function callback, but I'm not sure if that's what you were intending. You could use the `.bind()` method to pass it to the function directly: `redirectPage.bind(this, this.href)`.

The second problem is that you can't scroll to an element in a hidden container. Either scroll to the element in the `fadeIn` callback, or scroll to it *after* the `fadeIn` animation starts:

```js
$("a.transition").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".container").fadeOut(500, redirectPage.bind(this, this.href));
});

function redirectPage(link) {
  $(".container").fadeIn(500);
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = link;
  }, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="A">This is A <a href="#B" class="transition">Go to B</a>
  </div>

  ...some large text...

  <div id="B" style="margin-top: 3000px;">This is B <a href="#A" class="transition">Go to A</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Josh, it works perfectly. I owe you a beer!